# How to change default menu items (such as Whole Page, Fit to width, etc) from DocumentViewer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I have this DocumentViewer which is working,

Xaml Code:

```
<DocumentViewer Document="{Binding XpsDocument}" Loaded="documentViewer_Initialized"/>
```

ViewModel Code:

```
void Load()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Package pkg = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    string pack = "pack://report.xps";
    PackageStore.RemovePackage(new Uri(pack));
    PackageStore.AddPackage(new Uri(pack), pkg);
    XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(pkg, CompressionOption.NotCompressed, pack);
    XpsSerializationManager rsm = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(doc), false);
    DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)CreateFlowDocument()).DocumentPaginator;
    ReportPaginator rp = new ReportPaginator(this, data);
    rsm.SaveAsXaml(rp);

    xpsDocument = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
}
```

### Problem

I wanted to Add some buttons to the Menu Bar. And I've found a solution to make it work, but it doesn't seem like a reliable approach.

[image]

### I've tried:

I've managed to find the a child with type of ToolBar and Count of 10 which is the default toolbar. But I'm not satisfied with my approach. Does anyone have a better idea?

```
private void documentViewer_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dv = sender as DocumentViewer;
    if (dv == null)
        return;

    var tb = FindToolbar(dv);
    if (tb != null)
        tb.Items.Add(new Button { Content = "askjsdfsdf"});
}
public ToolBar FindToolbar(System.Windows.FrameworkElement root)
{
    ToolBar target = null;
    int c = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        var child = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i) as System.Windows.FrameworkElement;
        if (child == null) continue;

        var menu = child as ToolBar;
        if (menu != null)
            if (menu.Items.Count == 10)
                return menu;

        target = FindToolbar(child);
        if (target != null) return target;
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Why not to override the defualt template of DocumentViewer?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that without messing up the View